# How does inhaled poison work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am playing a level 10 alchemist and I know that I can create poisons, as well as put them on weapons. However, there is a poison type that is inhaled and is airborne. After I read how it works, I searched "holding your breath", though all the sites show about holding your breath is about holding your breath in water and do not show how to calcuate the "fifty fifty" chance each round. So i looked on google and a lot of other sites, but didn't find an answer for this.

- How do you calcuate the "fifty fifty" chance each round?
- How much rounds can a creature hold it's breath?

Answer (score 1):

You can hold your breath 2 rounds per Constitution point, and keep holding it after these rounds for as long as you don't fail your saving throws. During the rounds you are holding your breath, there is a 50% chance you don't have to make a saving throw **against the poison**.

> A creature can attempt to hold its breath while inside the area to
>   avoid inhaling the toxin. A creature holding its breath receives a 50%
>   chance of not having to make a Fortitude save each round. See the
>   rules for holding your breath and suffocation. If a creature is
>   holding its breath and fails the constitution check to continue doing
>   so, rather than suffocating it begins to breathe normally again (and
>   is subject to the effects of the inhaled poison if still in the area).

Comment: This answer conflicts with the accepted answer from the duplicate question you linked. If you think the duplicate question's answer is wrong, you should post an answer there. This question will most likely be closed soon.

Comment: I rewrote the answer so that it is correct. I misunderstood the other answer at first :S

Comment: Better, although duplicates are not supposed to be answered themselves. They are generally closed and linked to the original question, so as to not collect different answers.

Comment: Although it isn't officially a duplicate yet. I'm not really sure what the approach should be then...